# I don't know what follows what in this sentence

Tags: modifiers

> Officials familiar with the calls say the **efforts** have not been a departure from the administration’s **efforts** over the past year to push oil producers to keep production levels high after Russia’s invasion of Ukraine, which has roiled global markets.(from The New York Times)

1. Which **efforts** is modified by "to push oil...."?
2. Which part is modified by "after Russia's invasion of Ukraine"(I don't understand the timeline, what is followed by "after... ", the officals say, the efforts, the administration's efforts, or to push oil...)?

Answer (score 1):

I would say "to push oil" goes to the administration's efforts. The earlier efforts are those that, while a bit different, accomplish that goal and thus "have not been a departure."

The Ukraine invasion caused a shortage of oil supply. Oil producers were urged (by the administration) to keep oil production levels high. So, that part would refer to the first "efforts."

Comment: Russia’s invasion of Ukraine happened in February this year. So, how could it be “over the past year”?

Comment: That is just referring to 2022, not a literal 365-day period of time.

Comment: Just to clarify my last comment. It's a colloquial phrase. If I said "over the last 8 months" I could be accused of saying that something happened every month for 8 months. If I say "over the past year" I am saying it happened sometimes in a year period, but I'm not being specific. If you want to know when or how many times, you'll have to seek clarification. It's intentionally vague. It is useful but can be confusing.

Comment: Aren't all 'the efforts' here 'the administration's efforts'? Hence 'a departure from' rather than a more general 'at odds with'. //  'Officials familiar with the calls say these recent efforts have not been a departure from _the administration’s previous efforts in the past year to push oil producers to keep production levels high after ..._.' This explains with greater clarity.

Comment: Well, the administration is just using their bullhorn, so their "efforts" are different than the "efforts" of oil producers. Their goals may be the same depending on their point of view. The administration wants to keep fuel prices low, but oil producers want profits.

Comment: I see what you are saying. It could be referring to the administration changing tactics. I was thinking that they were talking about a particular oil company or all of them in a compare and contrast method.